# adding DateTime.Now into Xaml file in xamarion.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add DateTime.Now in xamarin.forms in xaml Page
i wrote this code :

```
<DatePicker  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="Small" Date=DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss") Format="d"></DatePicker>
```

But it's gave an error in `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

section, it say :

Invalid value for Priority 'Date' : 'DateTime.Now.ToString'
and many other errors appear, how can i solve it ?

Comment: you either need to set the property in the code behind, or bind it in XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xaml:

```
<DatePicker Date="{x:Static system:DateTime.Today}" />
```

Add please:

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```